# import wpf to IronPython app

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

I'd like making IronPython WPF app' but VS says:

> ImportError: No module named 'wpf'

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580543/importerror-no-module-named-wpf-in-revit-environment-only-user-interface/27599805#27599805) but it doesn't work. 
I am not sure about where doing this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf')
import wpf
```

When I write this it says

> ImportError: No module named 'clr'

Answer (score 0):

First you might not want to have your import and something else on the same line. Always put your imports before whatever calls to a function your are making!

```
import clr
import wpf

clr.AddReference('IronPython.wpf')
```

and I believe your file should be in the same directory for .Addreference() to locate it. as far as I know, the latest IronPython 2.7 should come prepackaged with wpf, but then again your version might differ. I would recommend to update to the latest, or download the modules you are missing and drop them in the IronPython repository at their appropriate location!

Hope this helps!