# Revit Dynamo RevitPythonShell - Python Debugger - ImportError: No module named _wpf

Tags: python, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I'm trying to get the Revit python shell debugger working in my dynamo but I'm running into issues. It seems to run in Revit alright but I cant get the debugger in dynamo to work [as shown here.](https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/debugging-python-code/12729)

Also if anyone has any other methods for debugging python code in Revit, feel free to let me know!

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\db\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\db\view.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\db\collector.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\ui\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\ui\forms\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\ui\forms\flexform.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cmaltez\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.6\packages\RevitPythonWrapper\extra\rpw.zip\rpw\ui\forms\resources.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2021\AddIns\DynamoForRevit\IronPython.StdLib.2.7.9\wpf.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _wpf
```

Which is odd because it seems I have the package located in the directory from the install.
[image]

This is what my Dynamo looks like. its the getting started file that comes with RPW.
[image]

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I've added this path to my searching path here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Platforms\Net40" [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580543/importerror-no-module-named-wpf-in-revit-environment-only-user-interface).

Here is an image of my searching path:
[image]

RPS works in Revit but doesn't work in dynamo for debugging python scripts.

Here are the contents of wpf.py

```
#-*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-

def _():
    import sys
    if sys.platform == 'cli':
        import clr
        clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf') 
        
_()
del _

from _wpf import *
```

any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of testing different things, I finally tried to just open the `wpf.py` file and change the line:

`from _wpf import *`

to

`from wpf import *`

and I'm now able to access rpw in dynamo.

but I cant get the debugger working in pycharm still.

I also added the paths to the Net40 folder, the unzipped rpw folder that comes in the install, and the location of my iron python folder

[image]